# How to perform PUT operation to update an API in Jmeter?

Tags: json, jmeter

Below code is for POST API:

```
{
    "request": {
            "method": "GET",
            "urlPattern": "/identity/v2/users/7983739"
    },
    "response": {
            "status": 200,
            "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            "body" : "{ 'language': 'en‐US', 'phoneNumbers': [{'type': 'home','value': 8059662323}, {'type': 'office','value': 8053088006},{'type': 'mobile','value': 6502229400}],'addresses': [{‘address1': '419 State St’,’address2': '2nd Floor’,’city': 'Santa Barbara’,’state': ‘CA’,’postalCode': 93101,’country': ‘US’,’type': ‘shipping'}] }"
    }
}
```

Now, I want to update the body with the below data:

```
"body" : "{'language':'en‐US','phoneNumbers':[{'type':'home','value':8059662323},{'type':'home','value':6502229400}],'addresses':[{'address1':'419 State St','address2':'2nd Floor','city':'Santa Barbara','state':'CA','postalCode':93101,'country':'US''type':'shipping'}]}"
```

Can someone tell me how to do it using Jmeter...

Comment: Hope this video tutorial helps you [LINK](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IjV-RefzCfU)

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps:

1. Add [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) Sampler to your [Test Plan](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Test_Plan)
2. Configure host, port, URL, etc.
3. Select "PUT" from "Method" dropdown
4. Switch from "Parameters" to "Body Data" section
5. Provide new JSON value there

You might also need to add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) to send at least `Content-Type` header with the value of `application/json`.

See [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article for detailed information on how to get started with API testing using JMeter

Answer (score 0):

you can have the entire body in a variable and then user it here with ${variable}

you can also check here http://fabiouechi.blogspot.com/2011/03/jmeter-posting-json-data-to-web-service.html